How to manage "range" of the x-axis in SwiftUI Charts?
My chart
Apple chart
I would like to manage the time range between other values in chart so smoothly like it is in e.g. the iOS Health app. How to modify the range of the chart between e.g. a 3-mouth view and a 9-mouth view?
This is my code:
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ChartsV: View {
    @State private var isSheetPresented = false
    @State var contentHasScrolled = false
    @ObservedObject var dataStore: DataStoreVM
    
    @State private var type: Int = 0

    init(dataStore: DataStoreVM) {
        self.dataStore = dataStore
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                        .init(color: Color(uiColor: .systemBackground), location: 0.1),
                        .init(color: colorForType(chartType: type), location: 0.7),
                        .init(color: Color(uiColor: .systemBackground), location: 1.2)
                    ]),
                    startPoint: .top,
                    endPoint: .bottom
                )
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.6), value: type)
                .mask(
                    LinearGradient(
                        gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                            .init(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), location: -0.5),
                            .init(color: Color.black.opacity(0.5), location: 0.5),
                            .init(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), location: 1.5)
                        ]),
                        startPoint: .leading,
                        endPoint: .trailing
                    )
                )
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                VStack {
                    Text("Wykresy")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .opacity(0.5)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding()
                    
                    Chart(dataStore.entries) { entry in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("Month", entry.date),
                            y: .value("Total", valueForType(entry: entry, chartType: type))
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(colorForType(chartType: type))
                        .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 8, lineCap: .round))
                        .interpolationMethod(.monotone)
                    }
                    .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
                    .chartYScale(domain: getYMin()...getYMax())
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .chartXAxis {
                        AxisMarks(position: .bottom, values: .stride(by: .month)) { value in
                            AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.month(.abbreviated))
                            AxisTick()
                            AxisGridLine()
                        }
                    }
                    .chartYAxis {
                        
                    }
                    .animation(.timingCurve(0.2, 0.5, 0, 1, duration: 0.8), value: type)
                    Picker("Typ", selection: $type) {
                        Image(systemName: "dollarsign").tag(0)
                        Image(systemName: "fuelpump.fill").tag(1)
                        Image(systemName: "road.lanes").tag(2)
                        Image(systemName: "bubbles.and.sparkles.fill").tag(3)
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                    .padding()
                }
                .background(.thinMaterial)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
                .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing])
                
                NavigationBarV(backgroundColor: Color(UIColor.bgGradient1), title: "Wykresy", back: "Podsumowanie", contentHasScrolled: $contentHasScrolled)
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        BottomButtonV(bottomButton: BottomButtonM(icon: "plus", color: Color.primary)) {
                            isSheetPresented.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Picker("Typ", selection: $type) {
                        Text("weeks").tag(0)
                        Text("months").tag(1)
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 80)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
                NewEntryV(dataStore: dataStore) {
                    isSheetPresented = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func getYMax() -> Double {
        let maxValue = dataStore.entries.map { valueForType(entry: $0, chartType: type) }.max() ?? 1
        return max(maxValue, 1) * 1.1 // Możesz również dodać wartość do stałego minimum
    }

    private func getYMin() -> Double {
        let values = dataStore.entries.map { valueForType(entry: $0, chartType: type) }
        let maxValue = values.max() ?? 1

        // Jeśli wszystkie wartości są zerowe
        if values.allSatisfy({ $0 == 0 }) {
            return -0.1 // Ustal dolną granicę na -0.1
        } else {
            // Ustal dolną granicę na 5% górnej wartości
            return max(0, maxValue * 0.95) * -0.1
        }
    }
    
    private func valueForType(entry: Entry, chartType: Int) -> Double {
        switch chartType {
        case 0: return entry.value ?? 0
        case 1: return entry.quantity ?? 0
        case 2: return entry.trip ?? 0
        case 3: return entry.quantity ?? 0
        default: return 0
        }
    }

    private func colorForType(chartType: Int) -> Color {
        switch chartType {
        case 0: return .orange
        case 1: return .green
        case 2: return .blue
        case 3: return .purple
        default: return .primary
        }
    }
}

I would like the chart to display different data depending on the selected segment (first picker): expenses, fuel consumption, distance traveled and number of washes. Each point on each chart should be the sum of values ​​of a given type from each week, in the case of a weekly view, and each month, in the case of a monthly view. However, this is not the most important thing. Mainly, I would like to achieve smooth switching between x-axis ranges. This should smoothly narrow and widen depending on the selected view, so that it displays a range of about 3 months on the width of the view, and the division is made relative to the first day of the week (e.g. 4 Nov, 11 Nov, 18 Nov, 25 Nov, 2 Dec) or about 9 months, and the division displays only the names of the months.

Have you tried using .chartXScale(domain: ....),
see the docs, as I mentioned before?

Congrats on asking your first question on StackOverflow, Dawid! --- To help you get assistance faster in the future, you may want to create a code sample with this View and some sample data.  That way anyone assisting you can grab your code & data, make adjustments, and share those changes with you. Your datastore's contents aren't available to someone reading this. --- If you find it difficult to find things in the docs on this topic, you may find what you need in example projects elsewhere ( for example this one )
